# Grouping elements and run animations separately

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement $.groups().

The main idea is: if I have one element that depends on another element, I will group them, and only when others group's element stop running, start the animation of this element.

I got this:

```
/* mini-plugin */
var groups = [];
$.fn.extend({
    group: function (key, selector) {
        if (key < groups.length) {
            selector && groups[key].add(selector);
        }
        else if (key == groups.length) {
            groups.push( $(this).add( (selector||this )) );
        }
        groups[key] && (function(){
            while (groups[key].is(":animated"));
        })();
        return groups[key];
    }
});
```

But, it isn't working as I want (and I have no idea why!)

```
/* testing */
$("div").hide();

$("#div1").group(0).fadeIn(2000);
$.group(0, "#div2").fadeIn(3000);
$.group(0, "#div3").fadeIn(4000);
```

It should fadeIn the first div of group(0) and when finish the animation, fadeIn the second div of group(0)...

[I did an example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mquw7447/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery already implements this for you! Pretty cool, right?

For queueing async operations like animations and ajax requests - jquery uses [**promises**](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). Your code in your example in plain jQuery looks like:

```
// calling `.promise` on an element returns a promise for when its animations are over
$("#div1").fadeIn(1000).promise().then(function(){
    // .then chains promises, the code here only executes after the 
    // .fadeIn(1000) on #div1 is done

    // returning a promise from a promise will wait for it when continuing
    // a chain
    return $("#div2").fadeIn(1000).promise();   
}).then(function(){
    // because of the return value, this only runs after div2 is done 
    // animating
    return $("#div3").fadeIn(1000).promise();    
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw2ryoq2/)

jQuery also lets you aggregate these with `$.when` so you can wait for multiple values at once.

#### But why isn't my code working?

You did not define a static `$.groups`. you only put it on the prototype. So the second and third lines of usage don't work. Also, you have a `while` loop which would end up being infinitely running since JS is single threaded in this context.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about that... Reinventing the wheel is too hard kkk.. Many thanks!!