# jQuery Ajax Wait Each Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

```
$xy('#simpan').click(function() {

  $xy('input[id="cekbok[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    var data = (this.value);
    var div = (this.value);
    var str = window.location.href;
    var res = str.replace("wp-admin/options-general.php?page=katalogu-options", "/wp-content/plugins/katalog/includes/img/loading.gif");
    var loading = ('<img src="'+res+'">') ;


    $xy.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '../wp-content/plugins/katalogunique/proses2.php',           
        data: {
            id  : (this.value)
        },

        success:function (data) {
            $xy('#result'+div).empty();
            $xy('#result'+div).append(data);
            $xy('#tz'+div).remove();
        }          

    });  

  });
});
```

My function sends checkbox values to `proses2.php` in a loop but when I run this script it will run all ajax POST calls at once. I want run the ajax requests 1 by 1 or wait until finish, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by _it will run all ajax POST_? Explain a bit more pls. And, looking at `$xy('input[id="cekbok[]"]:checked')` you seem to have more than one `checkbox` with the same `ID` which is wrong as an `ID` must be unique in any given document! Post your `HTML` as well.

Comment: if i check 10 checkbox then it will run 10 Ajax post to proses2.php, yes checkbox ID is unique, this script already working but i want make it do 1 by 1... thanks

Comment: Ideally what are you trying to acheive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way that doesn't have recursion and uses a straightforward loop:

```
$xy('#simpan').click(function() {

    var url = '../wp-content/plugins/katalogunique/proses2.php';
    var d = $.Deferred().resolve(); // empty promise
    $xy('input[id="cekbok[]"]:checked').each(function() {
        var div = this.value;
        d = d.then(function(data){
            $xy('#result'+div).empty().append(data);
            $xy('#tz'+div).remove();
            return $xy.post(url, {id: div}); // this will make the next request wait
        });
    });
    // can d.then here for knowing when all of the requests are done.
});
```

Note I can "clever this up" with a `.reduce` shortening the number of lines from 6 to 4, but honestly I'd rather keep the looping construct OP is comfy with. This works because of promise chaining - basically when you return an action from a `then` it will wait for it before executing the next `then` you're chaining it to.

Let us examplify:

```js
function log(msg){ // simple function to log stuff
    document.body.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
}

var delay = function(ms){ // this is an async request, simulating your AJAX
   var d = $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(d.resolve, ms); // resolving a deferred makes its then handlers execute
   return d;
};

// $.Deferred.resolve() starts a new chain so handlers execute
var p = $.Deferred().resolve().then(function(){ 
    log("1");
    return delay(1000); // like in your code, we're waiting for it when we chain
}).then(function(){ // in the above code, this is the d = d.then part,
    log("2"); // this only runs when the above delay completes
    return delay(1000);
});

// and more like in the above example, we can chain it with a loop:
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].forEach(function(i){
     p = p.then(function(){
         log(i);
         return delay(1000);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that doing `$xy('#result'+div)` is likely a bad idea since you're querying your view layer for something you put there - consider keeping the relevant divs as an array and keeping references instead :)

Comment: Big fan of promises, so very cool. Better explain this one in more detail as it will confuse all but the deferred die-hards :)

Comment: I agree this is the cleanest solution

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks, I've added some words explaining it. I'll add a simple example.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I've added an example, let me know if this is better.

Comment: @SintaCumeliani I'm glad I could help, it's worth mentioning that a lot of things in jQuery return promises, so you can also for example wait for an animation this way (by returning an $("animatedElement").promise() from a `then` or `then`ing it). Happy coding. ([Example of chaining animations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29606832/1348195))

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie first - that should be a different question. That said - it's just not chaining them, you'd push them all into an array and then call `Promise.all(promises).then` (or in jQuery's case `$.when.apply(null, promises).then`)

Comment: The whole point of `d = d.then` is to chain the functions, if you want them to run concurrently then `$.when.apply` them.

Comment: FYI: `p = $.when(p, nextpromise)` does what I was suggesting: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/0rh8Lhv4/ No need for `$.when.apply` after all (unless I have missed something) :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function like this to do all calls one after the other:

```
$xy('#simpan').click(function() {
    var str = window.location.href;
    var i=0; things = $xy('input[id="cekbok[]"]:checked');
    (function doOneTask(){
        if (i++>=things.length) return;
        var thing = things[i];
        var data = thing.value;
        var div = thing.value;
        var res = str.replace("wp-admin/options-general.php?page=katalogu-options", "/wp-content/plugins/katalog/includes/img/loading.gif");
        var loading = ('<img src="'+res+'">') ;
        $xy.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '../wp-content/plugins/katalogunique/proses2.php',           
            data: {
                id  : thing.value
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $xy('#result'+div).empty();
                $xy('#result'+div).append(data);
                $xy('#tz'+div).remove();
            }          
        }).always(doOneTask);
    })();
});
```

**Note** : if you want to stop at the first fail, instead of doing the next calls as I do, replace `always` with `done`.

Comment: Isn't it `var data = thing.value;`? and obviously this is repeated.

Comment: @LShetty yes, forgot this change

Comment: Well done on getting in early, but initialising variables outside a recursive function, to be used inside it, smells wrong. Surely passing a reduced list keeps it all self-contained with no external dependencies or initialisation? PS. You are still referencing `this` all over the place inside the function, which is incorrect.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie When it's to be used in one place, I prefer to use the closure than to pass arguments. But there's no strong difference.

Comment: Fair enough: You missed one more `this`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a recursive function, passing the list (minus the first entry) back each time.

e.g. the calling code is reduced to just this:

```
$xy('#simpan').click(function() {
    LoadAjax($xy('input[id="cekbok[]"]:checked'));

});
```

and the LoadAjax is recursive like this:

```
function LoadAjax(elements) {
    // Exit when done
    if (!elements.length) return;
    var $this = elements.first();
    var data = ($this.value);
    var div = ($this.value);
    var str = window.location.href;
    var res = str.replace("wp-admin/options-general.php?page=katalogu-options", "/wp-content/plugins/katalog/includes/img/loading.gif");
    var loading = ('<img src="' + res + '">');

    $xy.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../wp-content/plugins/katalogunique/proses2.php',
        data: {
            id: ($this.value)
        },

        success: function (data) {
            $xy('#result' + div).empty();
            $xy('#result' + div).append(data);
            $xy('#tz' + div).remove();
            // Go recursive with the rest of the list
            LoadAjax(elements.slice(1));
        }

    });
}
```